# Return foreach result

Tags: php

I am able to print_r data from yahoo API in foreach loop. However, I am not able to return it in the last line of the function.

```
function callcontact_yahoo($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $guid, $access_token, $access_token_secret, $usePost=false, $passOAuthInHeader=true)
{
  $retarr = array();  // return value
  $response = array();

    $yahoo_array = array();
    $newList = "";
    // extract successful response
        if (! empty($response)) 
            {
                list($info, $header, $body) = $response;
                    if ($body) 
                        {
                            $yahoo_array = json_decode($body);

                            echo "<pre/>";
                                foreach($yahoo_array as $key=>$values)
                                    {                
                                        foreach($values->contact as $keys=>$values_sub)
                                            {
                                                $fields = $values_sub->fields;
                                                    foreach($values_sub->fields as $field)
                                                        {
                                                            $convers = $field->value;
                                                        }
                                                $oneemail   = $convers.",";
                                                //print_r($oneemail);
                                                //echo "</br>";
                                                echo "I am one email:  $oneemail </br>";
                                            } 
                                    }
                        }
            }
  return $retarr;
}
```

In the line of `echo "I am one email:  $oneemail </br>";`, there is where I can see all my email contact is listed. But how to return it as in `return $retarr;` Please help. I have tried to debug it but still not got the idea.

Comment: is this what you mean ?`$retarr[] = $oneemail`

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Put it below the line `echo "I am one email: $oneemail </br>";`

Comment: Yes I have. But it doesn't return anything.

Comment: you never assign $retarr, you just initialize it, that's why it returns nothing

Comment: Instead of `return $retarr;` write `print_r($retarr);` and check weather mails are printing or not

Comment: `echo " this is $retarrs </br>";` I am echoing it in the view page. I am able to print it below that, but not able to echo it in the view page.

Comment: Okay, thats fine. Now tell us how are you calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

you put it like this :

```
foreach($values->contact as $keys=>$values_sub)
{
    $fields = $values_sub->fields;
    foreach($values_sub->fields as $field)
    {
    $convers = $field->value;
    }
    $oneemail   = $convers.",";
    //print_r($oneemail);
    //echo "</br>";
    echo "I am one email:  $oneemail </br>";
    $retarr[] = $oneemail;
}
```

Comment: I am only able to var_dump it. But it doesn't come to the return.

Comment: echo it with index. like `echo $retarr[0]`

Comment: I even echo it `$retarr[0]` in the above of  `return $retarr;`, but still doesn't show me anything.

Comment: is `print_r($retarr)` before return doesnt show anything?

Comment: `print_r($retarr)` after the line of  `$retarr[] = $oneemail;` show the listed of email contact. But if I put it after the `}` closing of the `foreach($values->contact as $keys=>$values_sub)` it doesn't print anything.

Comment: print_r($retarr) before return doesnt show anything

Comment: wow, just gone like a ghost i presume :D. wait, i'll look again your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69586/discussion-between-randyka-yudhistira-and-alisa).